# Turning a refresh ImageView into a ProgressBar

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am doing a custom title for my android app and I want to have a refresh button like the Twitter app.
I am using a `RelativeLayout` an my ImageView is defined by:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/title_refresh"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
</ImageView>
```

In my `Activity` I have something like this:

```
refreshView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.title_refresh);
refreshView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        /* Make the refreshView turn into a progress bar. */
        startService(new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyService.class));
    }
}
```

I would like the ImageView to turn into a ProgressBar while I wait for my service to finish processing.
How is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the progress bar view into the `RelativeLayout` which overlaps the `ImageView` with `visibility:gone` and then play with `setVisibilty(View.VISIBILE)`/`setVisibilty(View.GONE)` on your `ImageView` and `ProgressBar`.

Maybe a `ViewSwitcher` could help you too.

Comment: Exactly what I did too. Works quite well.